# Using custom domain for an IIS app running on Azure VM

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

Sent from my Windows 10 phone
I have a problem in seeing up a custom finding to reach the website which is running on Azure VM.

Recently I have set up a new VM on Azure Virtual Network and let it run an php application as IIS. I have successfully configured custom DNS label so I can reach to the website with "http://hogehoge.japaneast.cloudapp.azure.com".

However, I can't well get a way to set up a custom domain, for example, "http://hogehoge.net". I made some search and managed to create a new DNS Zone, and then I also added a CNAME record, which is shown in the attached image, to it.

But I can't reach to the site. I know it is probably matter of course since I didn't configure DNS registrar. Also I haven't yet purchased the domain.

I think I made some mistake in my procedure. Could anyone point out what is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your machine is not using the Azure DNS nameservers by default. You should add the CNAME/A records in your domain registrar's records, not in Azure DNS.

Comment: So then do I have to make some commands in a domain registrar which is an external service than azure? I know there are various domain providers and suppose azure doesn't have such a service independently. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is right. Though it is possible to purchase domains in Azure at least for Azure App Service. These are in the end handled by GoDaddy though. Another option you have (if possible with your DNS registrar) is to tell the registrar that you wish to use these nameservers instead of the default ones that they provide.

Comment: Thanks, I have succeeded to register a new domain at a registrar service and successfully let the site be able to be reached with "http://www.hogehoge.net/", I still would like to remove "www" if possible though.

Comment: "www" was omitted by the commnet converter... the url has it.

Comment: In Azure App Service we do this typically by pointing domain.com with an A record to the static IP address, and then make a CNAME record for www that points to for instance hogehoge.japaneast.cloudapp.azure.com

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I managed to do it. I think it is not a good way to use A record unless I don't make the site have a static (reserved) ip address because it is pointed to a specific ip and it will no longer be able to navigate users to the site once it is changed. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, but you can make public IP addresses static in Azure if you want to.